# Weird behavior of ocl matrix in opencv

Tags: opencv, opencl

I am faciong a qweird problem. I have two matrix, input and output. For each element i in a row r in the input matrix, 
it sums all element before i in that row and put the sum in i th column and r th row in output matrix. 
When I do this for small matrix, it gives me no problem. But for a big matrix (604x454),
the output matrix contains GRARBAGE value in all output matrix rows except the first row.

```
"__kernel void "
            "  v2_integral_cols_sum(__global uchar *src,\n"
                    "int rows,int cols,__global int *lm_sum, int pixels,int steps,int o_steps)\n"
                    "{\n"

                "int gid=get_global_id(0);\n"
                "if(gid>=pixels)"
                "return;\n"
                "else \n"
                "{"
                "int x = gid % steps;\n"
                "int y = gid / steps;\n"
                "int sum=0;\n"


                "for (int i=0;i<=x;i++)"
                "{\n"
                    "sum=sum+src[y * steps + i];\n"
                "}\n"

            "lm_sum[y*o_steps + x]=sum;\n"


        "}"

    "}\n"
```

interestingly if I use the printf statement after the output assignment statement  as in this block,I get correct output matrix.
I do not find any explanation of this weird behavior. Anyone can help me?

```
"lm_sum[y*o_steps + x]=sum;\n"
 "if(gid==640)\n"
            "{"

            "printf(\"lm_sum [%d %d %d] %d  \",x,y,gid,lm_sum[y * o_steps+ x]);\n"


            "}\n"
```

Comment: could you edit your question with the way you compute steps and o_steps as well as the kernel call (global size and dimension especially). Regarding the weird printf behavior, is it really the output matrix that contains the correct values or only what printf displays on the screen?

Comment: global size size_t gt[3] = {src.rows*src.step, 1, 1}, lt[3] = {32, 1, 1}; the out put matrix that contains the correct value. I did not use printf to print the output. It just print a string. I tried to use barrier instead of printf but that also did not give correct result.